# Creating a test for Domain Layer that contains Repository and unit of work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, repository-pattern

I have been trying to create a UnitTests for my project that is built using [Repository and unit of work](https://github.com/Arch/UnitOfWork)

here is my code so far

```
public async void Test1()
{
// Arrange
    var dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<Organization>>();
    var dbContextMock = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
    dbContextMock.Setup(s => s.Set<Organization>()).Returns(dbSetMock.Object);
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
    builder.UseInMemoryDatabase("Organization");
    var options = builder.Options;
    var loggingService = new Mock<ILogger<OrganizationDomain>>();
    var loggerFactory = new Mock<LoggerFactory>();
    var mockContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>(() =>
        new ApplicationDbContext(options, loggerFactory.Object));
    var unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork<ApplicationDbContext>>();
    var mappingService = new Mock<IMapper>();
    var mockOrganizationRepository = new Mock<IOrganizationRepository>();
    unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.GetRepository<Organization>(true)).Returns(mockOrganizationRepository.Object);
    var mockOrganizationDomain =
        new OrganizationDomain(unitOfWork.Object, mappingService.Object, loggingService.Object);

// Act
    var result = await mockOrganizationDomain.SearchOrganization("TEST");

// Assert
    Assert.True(result.Status == ResultStatusEnum.Success);
    Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```

here is the issue, `dbcontext` is null when debugging domain during test
so I tried creating it like this this

```
    var unitOfWork =
        new Mock<IUnitOfWork<ApplicationDbContext>>(() => new UnitOfWork<ApplicationDbContext>(mockContext.Object));
```

but it throws a different error

> System.ArgumentException : Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking the `DbContext`, use the InMemory provider for your tests. It might not be the best way to "test" the repository code, but its a good way to mock the `DbContext` out for you.